# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ext' of undefined jquery datatable while adding html5 buttons

Tags: jquery, datatables

Find my code below to load datatable

```
var url = './findAllStoppageReport';

         $('#table').DataTable( {
             dom: 'Bfrtip',
             buttons: [
                 'excelHtml5',
                 'csvHtml5',
                 'pdfHtml5'
             ],
            "ajax": {
                "url" : url,
                "data" : {
                    "frmDate" : startDate,
                    "toDate" :endDate,
                    "vehicleId" :selectedVehicle,
                    "crewId" :selectedDriver,
                    "headName" :headName,
                    "driverName" :driverName,
                    "stoppageTime" :stoppageTime
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "tripDate" },
                { "data": "tripId" },
                { "data": "location"},
                { "data": "stopStartTime"},
                { "data": "stopEndTime"},
                { "data": "totalStopTime"}
              ]
        } );
```

I have added all the required plugins for datatables

> Output:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ext' of undefined
>   jquery datatable

Comment: Where you have added html5 button plugin?

Comment: Load DataTables before Buttons. After all, Buttons is an extension for DataTables!

Use the https://datatables.net/download/ if you want it to figure out the load order for you.

Comment: Can you just show me the example